# Append file A.txt to file B.txt located in all subdirectories in linux command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cat

How to go through all files in the current directory and append file A.txt to file B.txt by Linux command line? File A.txt is located in the current directory. File B.txt is located multiple times in all subdirectories in the current directory. If I wanted to do it only once, I can do '''cat A.txt >> B.txt'''

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
find . -type f -name 'B.txt' -exec bash -c 'cat A.txt >> "$1"' -- {} \;
```

or

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/B.txt; do
    cat A.txt >> "$file"
done
```

or

```
find . -type f -name 'B.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 -I% sh -c 'cat A.txt > %'
```

Comment: Can you show an example of using xargs too? I was trying this : find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0  | xargs --null -L 1 -I F -t -p bash -c "cat ~/.bash_profile >> F" But it did not work for me

Comment: `>>` needs to be quoted and handled in a subshell. If it's unquoted the parent shell will perform the redirection before `find` even starts.

Comment: `xargs` way added